# What is the simplest way of chaining together animations using promises?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to chain together a few animations created with the `requestAnimationFrame` method (no jQuery used). Because of the way `requestAnimationFrame` is implemented, timing the successive animations with `setTimeout` doesn't produce the desired result. Hence, I'm attempting to accomplish my objective using promises.

As a JavaScript tyro, I'm still struggling a bit with this whole promise concept. Could someone please tell me why the (admittedly naive) approach taken below doesn't work? Many thanks in advance!

```
var animation1 = function(){
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    var t = 0;
    var runAnimation = function(){
        if (t < endValue) {
            t++; 
            // do animation stuff
            requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation)
        }
        else{return promise}
    }
    runAnimation();
}

var animation2 = function(){
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    var t = 0;
    var runAnimation = function(){
        if (t < endValue) { 
            t++;
            // do animation stuff
            requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation)
        }
        else{return promise}
    }
    runAnimation();
}    

animation1().then(animation2());
```

Comment: Try this: `animation1().then(animation2);` Removed brackets after `animation2`. Also add `runAnimation()` at last line in both methods animation 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi, may bad, I copied the code wrongly. (Sorry, now corrected.) Anyway removing the brackets after animation2 doesn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: There is no difference between `requestAnimationFrame` and `setTimeout` in regard to promises.

Comment: Your approach mostly doesn't work because your functions don't `return` anything. And don't resolve their promises asynchronously.

Comment: +Bergi: I meant that tricks like `setTimeout(animation2,4000)` don't work, because, given the implementation of `requestAnimationFrame`, there's no guarantee that animation1 takes exactly 4s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a Promise from the function

```
var animation1 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var t = 0;
      var runAnimation = function(){
          if (t < endValue) {
              t++; 
              // do animation stuff
              requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation)
          }
          else{resolve()}
      };

      runAnimation();
   });
}
```

Same for `animation2`

And chaining should look like this

```
animation1().then(animation2) //<-- pass function not the result of its invocation
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; great answer! A follow-up question (if you have time for it): what to do if the second animation function takes an argument (such as animation duration or initial position of the animated object)?

Comment: @KimFierens Then you could use `animation2.bind(thisContext, argument)`, or alternatively, make a function `makeAnimation2(arg)` which will return a function that will be called after `animation1` is finished.

Comment: If you decide to create another function don't forget to return if you need further chaining `animation1().then(function(){ return animation2(10, 20)})`

Comment: +Aurel Bílý and Yuri Tarabanko: Many thanks; now I know everything I need (for the time being).

Comment: You should promisify `requestAnimationFrame` only, so that errors from the rest of the code are caught implicitly